# Livereload after save but keep some objects

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Livereload for development purposes: after save the application should reload the GUI entirely.

But there are some C++ objects (used in QML code) that should stay and find themselves in the new version of the GUI.

Possible approach is to add to such object a string property that will be the same in the newely-loaded QML code, so it'll attach to that. Obviously, the object has two parts: the QObject and Qt-independent implementation.

There is a problem with that: the other bindings need such object to be already attached. These signals/properties mustn't arrive earlier.

I'm thinking about setting that 'persist' property in the `Component.onCompleted`, so it'll be like atomic with the C++ constructor. Will it work? Other suggestions? How do you do it?

Comment: So, you want something like `Component.onCompleted` for your C++ objects, don't you? Are those objects inyected from C++ as context properties, or custom components implemented in C++ and used in QML code?

Comment: @Jairo, they are custom C++ items that used in QML. And I wanted bindings to work, so any bindings must be delayed until these components are ready. But the tags that say which is which are ordinary bindings that are evaluated in random order with everything else. Longer pist: https://forum.qt.io/topic/62100/add-another-component-oncompleted-signal So, for now I'm wrapping each setter to delay the evaluation of all bindings during the init phase (which means creating the scene in two steps with QQmlComponent::beginCreate and QQmlComponent::completeCrete).